# Styling a heading using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I am displaying subheadings styles like this:

[image]

This looks fine until the text to be displayed exceeds a single line, when it looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to get is this:

[image]

i.e. the height of the decorative orange rectangle at the left should vary according to the height of the text.

Because we have a requirement that the decorative rectangle can be any colour, it is not done using an image.  This is what we currently render:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="decor">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>Text goes here</h3>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can style this using CSS to get the desired look?  I'm happy to change the HTML used too.  My restrictions are:

1. It must be possible for us to set the rectangle to any colour via CSS.
2. The heading text can vary, so we cannot apply specific hard-coded heights to specific headings via their IDs, it needs to work automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TkRsa/)**

**CSS**

```
h3{
    border-left:5px solid #F1592A;
     background-color:#EEEEEE;
    padding:2px;

}
```

Comment: Of course!  I feel a bit silly now.  Couldn't get out of thinking of borders as just thin lines around a box!

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using `&nbsp;` for styling (and keeping space is styling).

[Padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) is used to create inner element-spacing. And that's what you need.

Try adding the following CSS styling:

```
h3 {
   padding-left: 10px; /* You can change this number */
}
```

You can create the left "decoration" by adding a [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border):

```
h3 {
   padding-left: 10px; /* You can change this number */
   border-left: 3px solid orange; /* You can change the color and width */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/5SaCt/ . Set the left border to any color you want.
**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    1,2,3,4 <br/>
    5,6,7,8
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    border-left:5px solid orange;
    padding:5px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 
[image]